# unable to open browser from C#

Tags: c#, windows, browser

References in project snippet:

[image]

I am trying to open browser for google url but it throws an error. Kindly see the code snippet and devise any solution.

Do I need to install any third party library or something like that?

Comment: whats your .net version ?

Comment: .Net version is 4.5.2

Comment: Show full form code, not image post the code

Answer (score 0):

You should reference System

```
  using system;
```

or add reference to the project.

I tried the same code and it works.

[image]

Add reference out here for system.

Right click on References and select Add reference.

[image]

Make sure you have system checked and then click ok. It should be added to the reference.

Comment: i have added that name space. probably its not the case.

Comment: Have you added as a reference in the project ?

Comment: i don't know to add as a reference . And my Analyzer window doesn't contains any references.

Comment: now i have added picture of how my project analyzer window looks like.